# Placement of a refractory wall excess temperature sensor?

Tags: control-engineering, heat-transfer, sensors

I am working on a burner management system for a gas/coal fired pulp dryer. We are providing a thermocouple temperature switch on the roof of the firebox for an Excess Temperature Limit Interlock (per NFPA86 8.18.2). The code is ambiguous and the manufacturer of this old dryer has long been out of business. Some sources are recommending the temperature be measured in the refractory, while others are recommending direct measurement. Below the surface increases the reliability of the sensor while exposed gives you quicker response and slightly more accurate data.

Is it industry best practice (and/or code compliant) to install the thermocouple just below the fire side of the refractory surface, and calibrate for the small temperature reduction or should the sensor extend into the firebox?

> **NFPA86 excerpts:**
>
> "8.18.2.6* The temperature-sensing components of the excess temperature limit interlock shall be rated for the temperature and atmosphere to which they are exposed.
>
> 8.18.2.7* The temperature-sensing element of the excess temperature limit interlock shall be located where recommended by the oven manufacturer or designer."
>
> "A.8.19.8 The sensing element should be positioned where
> the difference between the temperature control sensor and
> the excess temperature limit sensor is minimized. The
> temperature-sensing element of the excess temperature limit
> interlock should be located where it will sense the excess temperature
> condition that will cause the first damage to the furnace
> or work as temperatures within the furnace rise above the
> maximum operating set point most critical to safe operation."